# Read a text file containing random sized integers separated by a space

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, io

My text file contains integers like: `123 879709789 43536 8768768`

I want to read whole number in one array index like array[1]=123 array [2]=879709789.

Here's what I've tried:

```
ifstream myfile("numbers.txt");

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( myfile.good() && !myfile.eof() )
    {
        for(i=1; i<myfile.eof(); i++)
        {
            myfile >> ar[i];
            if(ar[i]=="")
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wanna show what you tried?

Comment: Have you tried something on your own? From as your question is now, we don't see any effort of yours to somehow solve it on your own.

Comment: ifstream myfile ("numbers.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open()){
                        
    while ( myfile.good() && myfile.eof() ){
          for(i=1; i<myfile.eof(); i++){
                   myfile >> ar[i];
                   if(ar[]==""){
                               i++;
                   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>


std::ifstream infile("myfile.txt");   // or just use `std::cin`

std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int> { infile },
                   std::istream_iterator<int> { } );
```

Now `v` contains all your numbers. If there's an input error anywhere along the way, you won't see it and input will stop. If that's an issue, use a `getline`/`istringstream` approach, as has been documented in hundreds of similar questions on this site.

Comment: expected `,' or `...' before '{' token GOT THIS ERROR on code       int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
std::ifstream infile("numbers.txt");   // or just use `std::cin`
if(infile.good()){
std::vector<int> v(std::istream_iterator<int>{infile}, std::istream_iterator<int>{});
}

Comment: @user2062703 It could be that you don't have C++11 support, in which case you can replace the curly brackets by round ones.

Comment: Yes () brackets worked. Thanks for up till now. plz tell me how to iterate through my whole numbers and display them.

Comment: Visited website but it do not display any output? any suggestions?

Comment: @user2062703: If you don't have C++11, you can either use an intermediate variable for the iterators, or write `v((std::istream_iterator<int>(infile)), std::istream_iterator<int>())` (note the extra parentheses).

Comment: @Kerrek SB Unable to print anything. Plz be specific like how i can get the out put, ideone.com code is not complete. Waiting